# Bitcointools for v0.8+?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind

I was looking to poke around about with some of the functions of https://github.com/gavinandresen/bitcointools but it claims to only work for earlier versions of bitcoin.  Am i just out of luck? or is there another solution?

Comment: What functionality exactly do you want? Perhaps there are alternatives now.

Comment: I think he just created those tools when the current version was 0.7.*. Chances are high that some or even most of them still work.

Comment: You could always use [an earlier version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/bitcoin-0.7.2/)

Comment: @NickODell RE: using older version see: http://bitcoin.org/may15.html

Comment: @PieterWuille i want to be able to search blocks. with bitcoin tools the command is: dbdump.py --search-blocks= ...

Comment: I think those tools were written around 0.3.2x. What do you mean by 'search blocks'?

Comment: Print out all blocks involving transactions to the Bitcoin Faucet:
  dbdump.py --search-blocks=15VjRaDX9zpbA8LVnbrCAFzrVzN7ixHNsC

Comment: I Want to be able to search the blockchain for all transactions for a certain public key.